# python -m site -help print frozen [--user-base] [--user-site]

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD0Zo.png)

I want to change the default installation path of pip install for python, but when I use the command pip -m site -help, the file location of site.py is not printed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.